# What is the correct way to return an 'Invalid Value' type in C++, without the use of pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, return-value

I often use `-1` as the invalid value type when returning from a function, where the input yields incorrect output. For instance, writing an indexing function where the index is out of bounds, instead of throwing an exception, `-1` can be returned. But when writing a function that has negative values as possible return types, this technique does not work. What is the correct way to return an invalid type value in such instances?

The technique I use mostly is to set the return type to be of type `*int`, and return a Pointer to `NULL`. But, that requires all return values to be of a pointer type, which seems like an extra overhead to the function. Is there an accepted standard for returning values in such cases?

Comment: Why wouldn't you throw exception in such case?

Comment: You could have a function like the win32 `GetLastError()`. A better solution is to why not throw exceptions?

Comment: @Holt for instance a find function. You would return a valid index if found, but don't want to throw exception if the element is not found.

Comment: A lot of experts are still trying to figure this out. There are a few different standards proposals to facilitate different ways to do this.

Comment: How about creating an Error / Invalid Return community wiki for this?

Comment: My usual guideline is, if the function must fail because: a precondition wasn't met -> fail an assert; an exceptional, but perhaps recoverable at a higher-level, situation happened -> throw an exception; something terrible happened -> let it crash and it's debugging time. If the function can be expected to fail in a normal flow, like `std::vector::at`, then I make sure the return type is nullable (ex: a pointer, or `std::optional`) and return a null value on failure.

Comment: Dynamically allocating an optional return type is a code stink, but using a raw pointer instead of a `shared_` or `unique_ptr` is infinitely worse, as with the raw pointer - like always - ownership is unintuitive and the caller then becomes responsible for manually `delete`ing the value at some point. before `optional` was imported to `std`, I'd've settled for nothing less than a smart pointer. @Galik What about this do you think remains uncertain? `optional` has been accepted into `std` for C++17.

Comment: @underscore_d: what makes you think of `optional` as a smart pointer and why 'dynamically allocating'? A normal `optional` implementation naturally won't go to heap but have a buffer (not pointer, actual space) for T and use placement `new`. That's almost as quick as just returning T, there's absolutely no dynamic allocation and the buffer is reusable. Furthermore, `optional` is slicing just as values, as opposed to pointers.

Comment: @lorro Huh? My comment states that smart pointers are preferable to raw ones but are made irrelevant for this purpose by the arrival of `optional`. On your own answer, I specifically cite its value semantics as a distinct advantage. Anyway, for the above comment, I guess my wording was a bit labyrinthine (such is C++ ;-) It's useful in that it made you post a nice overview of how `optional` would typically achieve this!

Comment: @underscore_d : Yep, just misunderstood :). Btw, we might convert this to a wiki. While I personally totally like `optional` return types, there are quite some other solutions worth mentioning and comparing. Also lot of useful info in other's comments, not just mine :).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In newer C++, I'd suggest using `std::optional<>`; if you don't yet have it, `boost::optional<>`.

Comment: That's an interesting library I did not know about. But it is an instance type, so using the optional type versus an Integer pointer type doesn't have a large difference as compared to primitive types.

Comment: @iamseiko The difference is huge. A pointer has to point to something.

Comment: That would be the correct way to do it, yes.  Otherwise personally I would return bool true/false, passing the required return result by reference.

Comment: Ok, I can see why this is the best way to do this.

Comment: Btw, any sensible optional implementation has two neat features: 1. it has local storage for T (i.e., no `new`), 2. dereference has no overhead. (Mine has a third: it can be used in for loops :) )

Comment: @iamseiko "But it is an instance type" You say that like it's a bad thing! Who wants to faff around with having to dynamically allocate something if it's valid? _especially_ something like an `int`, which to me seems absurd to dynamically allocate. and I thought RVO, move semantics, etc exist largely to legitimise return-by-value. `optional` seems like an inevitable evolution of that thinking.#

Comment: @Robinson: had we had sg like `MyType myObj( DONT_RUN_CONSTRUCTOR )`, that'd be a correct way. Unfortunately, you cannot always predeclare your output variable as you might not have an appropriate constructor available. Sometimes you do - then it's just style which one you choose (till we have proper monads, then `optional` will be a bit ahead again).

Comment: @Robinson: Probably an '`optional`' that has the buffer either inside or outside (that is, referring), i.e., having `T* mValid` instead of `bool mValid`, but still having place for `T` inside would help. Then you could pass an optional ptr to your function (where to write T) and could still return `optional`. This has the disadvantage of being `sizeof(T) + sizeof(T*)` bytes, but all the advantages of both methods... What do you think?

Comment: Worth mentioning: `boost::expected` or `std::experimental::expected` is an `optional`-like that also lets you pack in an error message

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to let your function take a `bool&` as an output parameter used to indicate if the returned value is valid.

```
int myFunc(bool& valid); // sets 'valid' to true if result is usable, false otherwise
```

Users can then do

```
bool valid = false;
Int result = myFunc(valid);
if (!valid) {
    // Handle error
}
// Use result
```

Not the most pretty solution, but it does the job.

Comment: Isn't the other way around more idiomatic? expected result as reference and bool as return type, only if true is returned use the referenced variable.

Comment: It's really ugly, actually. If you really have to use `bool`s, return a `std::pair<T, bool>`.

Comment: I've seen both in real code, but the other way around is probably the most common. I did it this way around since OP seemed to want to keep the function returning `int`. And I agree that it *is* damn ugly.

Comment: I personally try to remove this wherever I see it, but if you really have to do this, at least have a default arg. Sometimes you *know* that the method will succeed and want to ignore error reporting. By def. error reporting should not have any overhead in this case. (As for the other way around, i.e., returning bool and taking an out ref, it's not just more ugly, it's plain wrong. You have to be able to provide some kind of 'default' constructed object just to have it overwritten by the fn. Yes, it'd be fun to have non-constructed objects, but we don't have it.)

Comment: @black: you can't do `std::pair<T, bool>` if you cannot construct `T` via some default method. What you might consider is taking a `const T&` for when error occurs (aka. default value).

Comment: @lorro: That would be a problem in highly generic code and there'd still be  partial solutions. But this is not generic code, so `T{}` (with `T = int` in the example) is fine and shouldn't it be, you do know how to construct it.

Comment: @black: a class without a default constructor is highly generic? Yes, for ints it works, but it doesn't scale.

Comment: @lorro: No, that's not what I meant to say. I wrote some [code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1abc2a11fb22104b) to clarify what I mean.

Comment: @black : Yes, I understand that it works for int. It doesn't work for MyType when it doesn't have a default constructor (or easy way of getting an object constructed). That doesn't need to be generic: it's an issue even if I only want my foo() to work for MyType (i.e., return `std::pair<MyType, bool>`)

Comment: @lorro: I can't see your issue. You _know_ the type and so you also know how to construct it. [See](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/092faaf56382eb3a).

Comment: @black : put `system("rm -rf /");` in the constructor unless the solution for a discrete logarithm problem is passed as input :). Really, as long as you can get an instance 1. quick 2. without side effects, it's ok - that's why I wrote that it works for int. Now, a getting an instance 1. might not be quick or even possible (assume a precondition for inputs that's hard to meet, a ptr to an interface type that only client code will implement, etc.), or might have side effects (opens a file). I do know that sometimes people introduce invalid just for this, but then you'll have to check everywhere

Comment: This is a terrible and disgusting idea, as the user has no means to check that the output is always called - also no compatibility with generic code.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the answer I provided above, there's a very clean, continuation-passing solution (given you're non-virtual):

```
template<typename Success, typename Failed>
void parse( const std::string& str, Success s, Failed f )
{
    auto a = start_parse(str);
    if( a.problem() )
        return f(); // you _might_ have an error code here

    s( finish_parse(str, a) );        
}
```

Then you might customize by:

- Success:

  - `[&i] (int i_) { i = i_; }`
  - `out(i)`, where `out(int& output_)` returns the above lambda for `output_`
  - actual code doing something useful
  - function to continue with
- Failed:

  - `[&i]{ i = 0; }`, `[&i]{ i = nullopt; }, or any other default value
  - `[] { throw MyFavouriteException(); }`
  - retry logic
  - `std::terminate()`
  - `[]{}` if you don't care (or if you're 100% sure it'll succeed)

It *might* look a little verbose, but IMHO:

- it's trivial to read
- any other schematics can be mimicked, even if there's no default c'tor

  - easy to change as well
- 'you don't pay for what you don't use', can surely be optimized away
- every schematic is visible and apparent from code:

  - for default value, caller sets it, not callee or global
  - `std::optional<>` and default value are handled the same
  - for exception, caller knows better what to throw
  - for no action, you don't have to lookup the implementation to know this
  - for `std::terminate()`, well, you know what to expect
  - if you 'speak' CPS, you might actually continue and save an `if` / `catch` / etc.

The only issue I see is constructor initializer lists. Any thoughts on this?